# Browse the matrix / Lee Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix

I have to do a method that will go through the matrix.I give the coordinates from the keyboard of the position [L, C], from where the extension will start.It will pass to the next value only if the next value is smaller than this.On the diagonals do not go! 
PS: Sorry for my english
Like in image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vM6od.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three steps need to be done here:

```
// prepare output matrix and fill it with -1
int[][] outMatrix = prepareOut(inputArray.length, inputArray[0].length);

// call recursively method to mark cells starting from the initial coordinates
outMatrix = markCell(inputArray, outMatrix, line, column, 1);

// print output matrix
printOutput(outMatrix);
```

The most relevant method implementation may be like this:

```
    static int[][] markCell(int[][] arr, int[][] out, int y, int x, int move) {
        int val = arr[y][x];
        if (out[y][x] == 0) {
            return out;
        } else if (out[y][x] < 0) {
            out[y][x] = move;
        }

        // checking a cell above the current one (north)
        if (y > 0 && out[y - 1][x] < 0) {
            if (cellMarked(arr, out, y - 1, x, val, move)) {
                out = markCell(arr, out, y -1, x, move + 1);
            }
        }
        // checking a cell under the current one (south)
        if (y < arr.length - 1 && out[y + 1][x] < 0) {
            if (cellMarked(arr, out, y + 1, x, val, move)) {
                out = markCell(arr, out, y +1, x, move + 1);
            }
        }
        // checking a cell to the left of the current one (west)
        if (x > 0 && out[y][x - 1] < 0) {
            if (cellMarked(arr, out, y, x - 1, val, move)) {
                out = markCell(arr, out, y, x - 1, move + 1);
            }
        }
        // checking a cell to the right of the current one (east)
        if (x < arr[0].length - 1 && out[y][x + 1] < 0) {
            if (cellMarked(arr, out, y, x +1, val, move)) {
                out = markCell(arr, out, y, x + 1, move + 1);
            }
        }
        return out;
    }

   static boolean cellMarked(int[][] arr, int[][] out, int y, int x, int val, int move) {
        final boolean marked = arr[y][x] <= val;
        out[y][x] = marked ? move : 0;
        return marked;
    }
```

When printing the output matrix, you replace remaining `-1` with `0`:

```
    static void printOutput(int[][] arr) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                char c = arr[i][j] <= 0 ? '0' : '*';
                System.out.print(c);
                System.out.print('\t');
            }
            System.out.print('\n');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`prepareOut` may be implemented like this:

```
    private static int[][] prepareOut(int rows, int cols) {
        int [][] out = new int[rows][cols];
        for(int[] row: out) {
            Arrays.fill(row, -1);
        }
        return out;
    }
```